# Newbie needs Javascript calculation formla

Tags: javascript, calculation

I am working on an Adobe Acrobat form and need a Javascript formula that will add Amount3 + Amount 4 then look to a dropdown box called Item7 which is either yes or no for sales tax.  If the box is yes, then the amount the amount will be 6% to be placed in Amount7, if not then enter .00.

Amount7 = (Amount3 + Amount4) * .06 unless Item7 = no

This is the last hurdle I have in completing this form.  I did try the Adobe community but the formulas they provided did not work.  Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `if(Item7 !== "no"){ Amount7 = (Amount3 + Amount4) * .06; }`

Answer (score 0):

### Is this what you're looking for?

```
let amount7 = amount3 + amount4;
if ( item7 === "yes"){
  amount7 *= .06
}
```

## *If so*
Your welcome